# Retrofit basic auth

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, interceptor

I have basic auth interceptor, which is not working..
I am not getting any errors, I do not have idea what is wrong with the code.
Credentials are 100% correct, error is not here.
I am also using Dagger Hilt 2 for dependency injection.

There is my code:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideApi(): Api {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor {
            var request = it.request()
            request = request.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", Credentials.basic("XXXX", "XXXX"))
                .build()
            it.proceed(request)
        }.build())
        .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(Api::class.java)
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what Credentials.basic does, but I just want to make sure you are aware that the value for the 'Authorization' header has to start with "Basic ", correct?

Comment: Can you add an example of api usage in your app?

Comment: Now I am just trying to print the fetched data, nothing more